# NTPD fails to find valid peers

Tags: ntp

I have a couple of Ubuntu servers that time and time again only receive peers with a stratum of 16. If I restart the ntp daemon a couple of times, eventually I will get one or two usable peers (with stratum 1 or 2).

I fail to find out why so often I get unusable peers. The servers are basic installs of Ubuntu 14.04 with a default ntp.conf and static IP (so no ntp config from DHCP).

What can be the cause of this problem and how can I solve this issue?

Comment: 16 means unreachable so it's likely a network issue. The daemon should attempt to reconnect on its own.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, I did sync successful to the peers that were listed with stratum 16, but I missed that I used ntpdate's '-u' switch when attempting this. After stopping ntpd and running ntpdate without that switch, I did indeed get a message indicating that the server couldn't be reached.

Comment: Do I interpret you correctly that this is no longer a problem for you?

Comment: Please add the non-comment lines of your NTP configuration to the question. Without this we can only be guessing at possibilities (it could be network ACLs, it could be the server selection, it could be something else entirely).

Comment: @JeffSchaller, I confirmed that NTP is being blocked on network level. My question has indeed been answered.